# SVD : Why right singular matrix is written as transpose

Tags: svd, matrix-decomposition

The SVD is always written as,

A = U Σ V_Transpose

[image]

The question is,
Why is the right singular matrix written as V_Transpose?

I mean lets say,
W = V_Transpose

and then write SVD as
A = U Σ W

SVD Image credit: https://youtu.be/P5mlg91as1c

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$V^T$ is the Hermitian transpose (the complex conjugate transpose) of $V$.

$V$ itself holds the right-singular vectors of $A$ that are the (orthonormal) eigenvectors of $A^TA$; to that extent: $A^TA = VS^2V^T$. If we wrote $W = V^T$, then $W$ would no longer represent the eigenvectors of $A^TA$.
Additionally, defining the SVD as: $A = USV^T$ allows us to directly use $U$ and $V$ to diagonalise the matrix in the sense of $Av_i = s_iu_i$, for $i\leq r$ where $r$ is the rank of $A$ (i.e. $AV = US$). Finally using $USV^T$ also simplifies our calculation in the case of a symmetric matrix $A$ in which case $U$ and $V$ will coincide (up to a sign) and it will allows us to directly link the singular decomposition to eigen-decomposition $A = Q \Lambda Q^T$. Just to be clear: "*yes, using $V^T$ instead of $W = V^T$ is a bit of convention*" but is a helpful one.

Answer (score 9):

It's written as a transpose for linear algebraic reasons.

Consider the trivial rank-one case $A = uv^T$, where $u$ and $v$ are, say, unit vectors. This expression tells you that, as a linear transformation, $A$ takes the vector $v$ to $u$, and the orthogonal complement of $v$ to zero. You can see how the transpose shows up naturally.

This is generalized by the SVD, which tells you that *any* linear transformation is a sum of such rank-one maps, and, what's more, you can arrange for the summands to be orthogonal.
Specifically, the decomposition
$$
A = U\Sigma V^T = \sum_{i = 1}^k \sigma_i u_i v_i^T
$$
says that, for any linear transformation $A$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ (more  generally, any compact operator on separable Hilbert space), you can find orthonormal sets $\{v_i\}$ and $\{u_i\}$ such that

1. $\{v_i\}$ spans $\ker(A)^{\perp}$.
2. $A$ takes $v_i$ to $\sigma_i u_i$, for each $i$.

A special case of this is the spectral decomposition for a positive semidefinite matrix $A$, where $U = V$ and the $u_i$'s are the eigenvectors  of $A$---the summands $u_i u_i^T$ are rank-one orthogonal projections. For Hermitian $A$, $U$ is "almost equal" to $V$---if the corresponding eigenvalue is negative, one has to take $u_i = -v_i$ so that $\sigma_i \geq 0$.

Comment: +1 Nice suggestion, I always like rank-1 approaches.

Comment: Another motivation is that $U=V$ is a useful and interesting property, but $U=W$ wouldn't be (as far as I can tell).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is much dumber than the others...

> lets say, W = V_Transpose
>
> and then write SVD as A = U Σ W

with that you are asking the reader to memorize one more variable ($W$) but for a simple expression as $V^T$ is just not worth it, IMO.